# Finding Accuracy, Recall, Precision, and F1 from Matlab Confusion Matrix

Tags: decision-trees, accuracy, k-nn, confusion-matrix, f1score

I'm working on a project to find the highest accuracy between KNN and a Decision Tree for Classification using Matlab.
How to calculate the Accuracy, Recall, Precision, and F1 from the output below? if the output already has TPR and FNR.

(please visit the following link to see the image)
https://freeimage.host/i/JxouSS4